# ODE existence of specific solutions

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have difficulties with this question :

Given the ODE named (1) : $$x'=y+\sin (x^2y)$$ $$y'=x+\sin(xy^2)$$

and the :

**Definition.** A *Petal* is a solution $(x(t),y(t))$ that verifies $\displaystyle \lim _{t \to \pm \infty} (x(t),y(t)) =(0,0)$.

How can I show that the exists at most two distinct *petals* ?

First I remarked that the question has sense since :

$$\|(x',y')\| \leqslant \|(x,y)\| + C$$ where $C$ is a wisely chosen constant. It follows that the solution $(x(t),y(t))$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$.

Next, the linearization in $(0,0)$ shows that $(0,0)$ is an hyperbolic point.

But how can I say more ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that the non-linear perturbation is not strong enough to alter the behaviour of the linearized dynamical system:

$\hspace2in$[image]

so there are no petals at all: solutions cannot cross each other, and if we rotate our reference system $45^\circ$ counter-clockwise, any solution stays in the same quadrant all the time.

Comment: Thank you, 
I also draw the field, but the question is to prove that there is at most two so it is possible that ther is no petals. But how do you prove this ?

Comment: @M.LTA: just prove my last sentence (about staying in the same quadrant all the time) by finding a suitable Lyapunov function.

Comment: Speaking about how to prove that there's no petals at all in this case. In short, no Lyapunov function is needed. It's easy to observe that $y=x$ and $y=-x$ are invariant sets for this system. Moreover, they must contain separatrices of saddle at the origin. Since $y=x$ and $y=-x$ intersect only at origin, separatrices don't intersect anywhere and no petal is possible in this case.

Answer (score 1):

What is important is that you've found that origin is a hyperbolic saddle point. There are exactly 2 trajectories in $\omega$-limit set (incoming separatrices) and 2 trajectories in $\alpha$-limit set (outgoing separatrices) (if we don't count the origin itself, but it's not needed here) — this is a consequence of Grobman-Hartman theorem. So this pretty answers your question: **if** there is a petal for this saddle, **then** it must contain one of the incoming and one of the outgoing separatrices. And since we have only 2 of each kind, we can't have more than 2 petals for hyperbolic planar saddle.

If I'm not confusing here, complex systems of form $\dot{z} = z^m, \; m>1,$ can be adjusted to have as many petals as needed.